# Can we name an ill-formed specialization as long as we don't instantiate it?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

```cpp
template <typename T, int N>
struct array {
    T data[N];
};

using bad_array = array<void, 0>;
```

In the above code, we are referring to a specialization of the `array` class template which is not instantiated. If it was instantiated, then the program would be ill-formed, because we would generate a `void data[0]` member.

Is this code ill-formed, no diagnostic required, or is it well-formed?

Comment: This is kind of the opposite of template specialization. This associates a new name with existing code. A template specialization associates new code with an existing name (in conjunction with specified template parameters in both cases). That said, yes, as long as you don't attempt to *instantiate* it, I think defining the name `bad_array` the way you have is well formed (i.e., I don't see anything that says a well formed type name must be one that can be instantiated).

Comment: [Seems to compile](https://wandbox.org/permlink/spIbIqufcZL07LKy), anyway

Comment: @PaulSanders: yes, but we expect that with code that's fill formed with no diagnostic required.

Comment: Ill-formed NDR is a really problematic thing to exist in a language, so it is only applied where it impossible or unreasonably hard for compilers to detect the ill-formedness. While I don't _know_ if this really is legal, I strongly assume so because this error would be rather simple to detect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is well-formed. I can't really provide you a standard reference, because it simply doesn't violate anything in it.

Nothing says that forming a type alias requires the type to be complete, nor does completeness of the type affect the behavior of the alias declaration and so there is no implicit instantiation according to [[temp.inst]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.inst#2). So, that the instantiation of the particular specialization would be ill-formed is irrelevant until you instantiate it implicitly or explicit in some other way.

And since also none of the items listed in [[temp.res.general]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.res.general#8) apply to your template, the compiler shall not issue any diagnostics for the template itself as required by the last sentence of [temp.res.general]/8.

When writing a template-id of anything but a function template, then regardless of context, the template-id must be *valid*, otherwise the program is ill-formed. The requirements for this are in [[temp.names]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.names#6) and include verifying that the number and kinds of template arguments are correct as well as that constraints are satisfied for non-dependent template-ids, i.e. all the syntactical requirements connected to the *declaration* of the template rather than its definition. But none of these requirements are violated by the template-id `array<void, 0>` either.